# Scrape Data from coinmarketcap.com in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

Im trying to build a database of historical performance of Bitcoin and a few other larger coins. To do this I want to extract the main table from this URL (with these particular dates) into r:

https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20170705

What would be the best package and method to do this in r?

Thanks

Comment: Um…they have an [API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rvest` package is helpful here:

```
library(rvest)

url <-read_html("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20170705")

table <- url %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Very clear, neat, and useful answer. A very good usage of `rvest::html_table` and `xml2::read_html`. Many thanks.